# How to align meshes with matching edges via Python

Tags: python, edges

So basically I have about 325 separate meshes, broken up like a jigsaw puzzle. Like a jigsaw puzzle each mesh edge has a partner mesh with a matching edge. I was curious to whether or not there was a way to use python to pick a mesh then search through all the other meshes until it finds its partner then align them based on their edges? Now I have no idea if this is even possible I have 0 knowledge on python, but I've spent about 3 hours trying to do it manually to no prevail! If anyone could shed some light on this I would very much appreciate it! Thank you!

Comment: Pictures are a good way to describe things too. The more info you add to your question the more likely to be answered. Would also suggest making a stripped down sample file with say 5 pieces (with at least 2 "matching") https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com

Comment: This is probably possible (but not simple, but... interesting...). Could you upload a blend file with these meshes as suggested by @batFINGER ?

Comment: Are the meshes 2D (planar) or 3D (volumes)?

Comment: Hey sorry guys! Never got a notification of responses! I'll get a demo of what I'm doing drawn up real quick and put on here!

Comment: Here is what I start with: 
[Starter Image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vcd7q4NnoUQtKmHkjoGHHMBIoH2nMfqk/view?usp=sharing)

Here is what I want:
[End Result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xqZBVCvMrYEroaUwwMi8RPkV3jWMfOD_/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the Demo File:
[Demo File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x6crd4YnHKf6FFm5wrCA85zPM_roMaK9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Not sure if anyone has had the time to take a look at this. But if you could help me come up with something that can do what my goal is, I'd appreciate it very much!

Comment: You could certainly build a couple of loops in python to do this, but what would qualify as a 'matching' edge? length? angles?

Comment: Doable and easier than we though, the edge is somewhat continuous and can build a dictionary for searching matching edges. As far as there is finite boundary and the edges is all look like quad, looping boundary edges and matching between them is feasible without complex algorithm.

Comment: Basically I am looking to match edges based on the vertices count and the location of the vertices. Two objects that have the same amount of vertices and the same position for each vertex. So for example: if mesh A has an edge that has 16 Vertices on the -x axis, then store each vertex vector in an array, then find another mesh(mesh b) with 16 vertices on the -x axis and store their vertex vectors in an array, then compare all 16 vertices of mesh a with all 16 vertices of mesh b and see if they match. If so, then move mesh along -x axis to match the vertices and merge those objects together.

Comment: @NoobPyBlender, general case is a bit complex (so long, imho). Are the parts rotated?

Comment: All objects are extracted from a game archive and the objects are offset and usually rotated in the correct rotation. Its really just aligning the meshes is what Im trying to do